# Django permissions not updating

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have setup permissions in my model class as follows:

```
class MeetingHistory(models.Model):
.....

    class Meta:
        permissions = (
            ("add_meeting_details","Can add meeting details"),
            ("change_meeting_details","Can change meeting details"),
    )
```

The `change_meeting_details` is a new permission I added however the django admin interface is not diplaying the new permission.

I tried the following so far(based on other similar questions):
- Run makemigrations app_name then ran migrate
- refreshed the browser page and deleted all cache

the issue still seems to persist. Any suggestions?

Comment: It's a known behaviour. Try this https://gist.github.com/magopian/7543724

Answer (score 0):

New permissions is creating on `post_save` signal, that is handling on global migrate.
Try to revert your last migrations and instead `./manage.py migrate app_name` do `./manage.py migrate`.

Comment: I tried it. It still is not updating the permissions